# Showing that $\ln(x) < x − 1$ for all $x ∈ (0, 1)$

Tags: calculus

How would I show that $\ln(x) < x − 1$ for all $x ∈ (0, 1)$?

I started by doing e to the power of each side giving me

$x<e^{x-1}.$

Then I said that

$$x<\frac{e^x}{e}$$ 
so $$ex<e^x.$$

Would I get anywhere doing this?

Comment: Hint:  $\log x = \int_1^x x^{-1} \ dx$, $x-1 = \int_1^x   dx$

Comment: Do you know the 'integral' definition of log? (I.e try writing log(x) as an integral)

Comment: So you assumed $ln(x) < x - 1$ to show that... $ln(x) < x - 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove the function $f(x)=x-\ln(x)-1$ is positive in $(0,1)$. Notice that the derivative is $1-\frac{1}{x}$, and is therefore negative in $(0,1)$. Since $f(1)=0$ and the $f'(x)<0\in (0,1)$ we have that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you did in the last sentence would you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: Oh wait I just got it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$y=x-1$ is the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y=\ln x$ at $(1,0)$ and $\ln$ is *concave*. So  the inequality is true for *all* $x>0, x\ne 1$.